# error: sigma must be positive definite

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to create truncated multivariate normal r.vector with sigma that depends on some random vector z. Since initially sigma (in my code called nn) is not positive definite, i used function `make.positive.definite()` and then i got nn to be positive definite (and symmetric).

But in calling `rtmvnorm` i get the following error:

> "Error in checkSymmetricPositiveDefinite(sigma) -sigma must be positive definite".

Any idea what might be wrong?

```
library(tmvtnorm)
library(matrixcalc)
library(corpcor)

zmean <- rep(0, 100)
zSigma <- diag(100)
z <- rmvnorm(n=1, mean=zmean, sigma=zSigma)

umean <- rep(0, 100)
usigma <- exp(-0.5 * rep(1, 100) + z)
nn <- t(usigma) %*% usigma

is.positive.definite(nn)

nn <- make.positive.definite(nn)
is.positive.definite(nn)
isSymmetric(nn)

a <- rep(0,100)
b <- rep(+Inf, 100)

U <- rtmvnorm(n=1, mean=umean, sigma=nn, lower=a, upper=b, algorithm="gibbs")
```

Comment: don't know but maybe you could try `Matrix::nearPD`  instead, with `ensureSymmetry=TRUE` ?

Comment: it doesnt seem to help, assuming i am using nearPD in correct way...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is related to machine precision. Your matrix is positive definite after transformation, however you used different precision tolerance level in `make.positive.definite` than the one used in internal `rtmvnorm` checks.

With your example:

```
is.positive.definite(nn)
[1] TRUE
```

However:

```
det(nn)
[1] 0
```

So any function using `det()` to get determinant of your matrix will see it as non positive definite. You can overcome this by making sure your `det(nn)` returns a positive value.

One way is to add some variance in all directions:

```
nn <- nn + diag(ncol(nn))*0.01
det(nn)
[1] 9.98501e-253
```

Now `rtmvnorm` works.

If you want to use `make.positive.definite()` you have to change the tolerance:

```
nn <- make.positive.definite(nn, tol=1e-3)
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks a lot for spending your time on explanation!